# PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA error at KeWaitForSingleObject function

Tags: windows, device-driver

Can this codes cause a problem?(PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA)

```
KEVENT waitEvent; //allocate on stack
LARGE_INTEGER timeout;

KeInitializeEvent(&waitEvent, NotificationEvent, FALSE);
KeResetEvent(&waitEvent);
timeout.QuadPart = -(100 * 10000); // 100 ms

while(pDataChannel->useCount)
{
    KeWaitForSingleObject(&waitEvent, Executive, KernelMode, FALSE, &timeout);
}
```

Can the waitEvent valiable be paged-out?
Is the variable must allocated on a non-paged pool?

Answer (score 2):

Is pDataChannel valid? Or are you running at `DISPATCH_LEVEL`?

These can lead to the error you have.

Comment: Thanks Christopher.

pDataChannel was allocated at NonPagedPool and it wasn't null.
And IRQL was PASSIVE_LEVEL at that moment.